# GeoServer timeseries WMS request - ncwms plugin

Tags: geoserver

I wanted to avoid looping through individual WMS requests, so tried to get date range data with [this plugin](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/ncwms/index.html).

After following instructions, got error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.geoserver.wms.ncwms.NcWmsService$DateFinder$2 tried to access private field org.geoserver.catalog.util.ReaderDimensionsAccessor.TEMPORAL_COMPARATOR (org.geoserver.wms.ncwms.NcWmsService$DateFinder$2 and org.geoserver.catalog.util.ReaderDimensionsAccessor are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @59474f18)
```

I am using GeoServer 2.20.0.

How can I resolve this?

Here is the request link:

```
http://79.101.20.138:8080/geoserver/fchannel/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetTimeSeries&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TIME=2023-03-05T20:00:00.0Z/2023-03-05T23:00:00.0Z
&QUERY_LAYERS=fchannel:t2m&STYLES=&LAYERS=fchannel:t2m&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fcsv&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=247&Y=217&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&width=566&height=419&BBOX=13.2730164888457%2C34.045000000000115%2C30.26948593598513%2C46.6150000000006
```

Comment: That's weird `TEMPORAL_COMPARATOR` is public (https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/a2fcb3c88c74026d0378663998bb8831b2bdb7e4/src/main/src/main/java/org/geoserver/catalog/util/ReaderDimensionsAccessor.java#L69) - are you sure you matched the versions of the plugin exactly to the GeoServer?

Comment: Used to be private, has been changed in this PR: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/commit/a2fcb3c88c74026d0378663998bb8831b2bdb7e4. So you need a newer GeoServer to work with the ncmws community module.... and it's a good idea to get at least 2.20.7, there are known security vulnerabilities in 2.20.0 anyways: https://geoserver.org/vulnerability/2023/02/20/ogc-filter-injection.html